# Tallit gadol used since bar mitzvah or since marriage

Tags: minhag, tallit-gadol

The custom to use tallit gadol from bar mitzvah is applied to Ashkenazi Jews from all regions were Western Yiddish was traditionally spoken? Or in some these regions (Dutch-speaking areas, Belgium, Luxembourg, Switzerland, Austria, part of Poland historically occupied by German Empire, Czech lands) the tallit gadol is used only after marriage?

Comment: I don't have sources but my understanding was that in Holland, Luxembourg, Switzerland, and Austria it was pretty standard pre WWII to wear a talis from bar mitzvah. I know Jews of Swiss origin and this is what they do. In Present day Czechoslovakia (Bohemia, Moravia, and Slovakia) and parts of Hungary it was more complicated as there were two groups of Jews the Chasidim and The Oberlanders. The Chasidism did not wear a tallis prior to marriage but the Oberlanders did.

Comment: See [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/115287). The basic idea is wearing a talit is a serious mizva and even some tanaim refrained from putting one on till marriage. Those who do wear at a younger age is either due to not wanting to lose out on the mizva for 20 odd years till one gets married (for historically they married earlier), or for the sake of chinuch banim.

Comment: @DavefromBaltimore Ashkenazi Jews from Belgium wear tallit gadol from bar mitzvah or from marriage? And the Ashkenazi Jews from historical German Poland?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a source, but I've been told that the overwhelming poverty was not as severe in Western Europe, so a relatively large piece of cloth was affordable, where as that was often not the case within the Pale.

By the way, Ashkenaz from Frankfurt begin wearing a tallis as toddlers

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question AFAICT